# Jquery function split to a separate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".terms").hide();

    $("#Options").change(function () {
        var optionId = $(this).val();
        if (optionId == 0) {
            $(".options").hide();
        }
        else {
            var option = $(this).find(":selected").text();
            option = option.split(' ').join('_')
            $(".options").find("#options_link").attr("href", "Options/+option+.html")
            $(".options").show();
        }
    });
});
```

basically I want to call this method on page read as well as .change on options

how would I split this function into it's own function? Main part that I am confused at is how to pass in the $(this) to the new function I will create

Update

I am now using this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".terms").hide();
    $("#Options").change(updateOptions); // onchange
    $.proxy(updateOptions, $('#Options'))(); // onload
});

function updateOptions() {
    var optionId = $(this).val();
    if (optionId == 0) {
        $(".options").hide();
    }
    else {
        var option = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        option = option.split(' ').join('_')
        $(".options").find("#options_link").attr("href", "Options/" + option + ".html")
        $(".options").show();
    }
});
```

but basically I want to also call this when the page is loaded. I can't use UpdateOptions() as (this) will be nothing?

Comment: I guess you'll have to copy the same code for onload event and  replace `$(this)` with `$('#Options');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to separate the logic to a function and call it under the relevant events. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".terms").hide();
    $("#Options").change(updateOptions); // onchange
    $.proxy(updateOptions, $('#Options'))(); // onload
});

function updateOptions() {
    var optionId = $(this).val();
    if (optionId == 0) {
        $(".options").hide();
    }
    else {
        var option = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        option = option.split(' ').join('_')
        $(".options").find("#options_link").attr("href", "Options/" + option + ".html")
        $(".options").show();
    }
});
```

Note that I used `$.proxy` to maintain the scope of `this` within the function. Also I fixed what I assumed was supposed to be string concatenation of the `option` variable.

Comment: This does seem to work, but the problem is, if I click submit and the model is invalid, the page will refresh, now the option is still selected, but the option at the bottom is hidden, how can I tell it to check? I could run the updateOptions method on ready, but it still thinks nothing is selected

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `change()` right after defining the `onchange` handler:

```
$("#Options").change(function () {
    var optionId = $(this).val();
    if (optionId == 0) {
        $(".options").hide();
    }
    else {
        var option = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        option = option.split(' ').join('_')
        $(".options").find("#options_link").attr("href", "Options/+option+.html")
        $(".options").show();
    }
}).change(); //append change() here
```

For those who don't understand this simple answer (including the OP), try reading this jQuery documentation about [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a separate function then call them in each event like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".terms").hide();

        options($("#Options"));
        $("#Options").change(function(){
            options($(this));
        })
    });

    function options(optionsElem) {
            var optionId = optionsElem.val();
            if (optionId == 0) {
                $(".options").hide();
            }
            else {
                var option = optionsElem.find(":selected").text();
                option = option.split(' ').join('_')
                $(".options").find("#options_link").attr("href", "Options/+option+.html")
                $(".options").show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing *this* to any function you can do...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".terms").hide();

    $("#Options").change(function () {
       Myfun();
    });

    function Myfun(){

        var optionId = $("#Options").val();
        if (optionId == 0) {
            $(".options").hide();
        }
        else {
            var option = $("#Options").find(":selected").text();
            option = option.split(' ').join('_')
            $(".options").find("#options_link").attr("href", "Options/+option+.html")
            $(".options").show();
        }
    }
});
```

You can also call this function onload.